# updated into System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2019

full error- System.InvalidOperationException:'Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek.'

my code worked perfectly, until i updated. now it throws the above error. when i already know that the code works i struggle to understand a way to fix it. i tried doing what was suggested in the error message but that make my code stop and await input every loop, i want the hotkeys to interact with the application not grind it to a halt

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo click = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
if (click.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 || click.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1) { ... }
do {
while (Console.KeyAvailable == false) { ... }
click = Console.ReadKey(true);
            } while (click.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

what i found out, no thanks to this website, was it had nothing to with the update it was because i wanted "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show" to work so i put
"< UseWindowsForms>True</ UseWindowsForms>" into the json file and that was causing conflicts. if anyone else runs into the same problem i had making "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show" work than make a console app in the .net framework not the core